Google Log Keeper finding root - _releaseLock
I have the following error reporting in my google app engine project. This error occurs outside of anythin I think I have control over. Could I ask for some pointers on how to resolve?

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"/layers/google.python.runtime/python/lib/python3.12/logging/init.py",
line 243, in _releaseLock
def _releaseLock():


Similiarly I have
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/layers/google.python.pip/pip/lib/python3.12/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 282, in handle
    keepalive = self.handle_request(req, conn)

I do not believe this is any code I have control over?
